# Simple generic auto __repr__

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, reflection, meta-programming

## Preface

At some point I was tired of writing & supporting `__repr__` methods, so I've decided to write it once and reuse everywhere in my classes.

Since I'm trying to write classes as simple as possible, most of them ends in something like

```
class MyClass:
     def __init__(self, param, other_param, ...):
         self.param = param
         self.other_param = other_param
         ...
```

i.e. initializer parameters names corresponds to fields names, so we can get initializer arguments by simply `getattr`'ing corresponding fields.

Main ideas are:

1. I want to have informative string which includes parameters involved in instance creation. For simple cases it should be possible to copy string & paste in some place (e.g. REPL session) and have similar object definition with as less work as possible. This helps a lot during debugging sessions, logging, especially in failed test cases with randomly generated data.

   Great examples are `Counter` & `OrderedDict` from `collections` standard library:

   ```
   >>> from collections import Counter
   >>> Counter(range(2))
   Counter({0: 1, 1: 1})
   >>> Counter(range(2)) == Counter({0: 1, 1: 1})
   True
   >>> from collections import OrderedDict
   >>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(range(2))
   OrderedDict([(0, None), (1, None)])
   >>> OrderedDict.fromkeys(range(2)) == OrderedDict([(0, None), (1, None)])
   True
   ```
2. Once signature change, `__repr__` should handle this automatically for simple cases like renaming/removing/changing order of parameters.

## Attempt

*Note*: following code requires Python3.5+ due to `yield from` statement

```
import inspect
from collections import (OrderedDict,
                         abc)
from typing import (Any,
                    Callable,
                    Iterable,
                    TypeVar,
                    Union)

Domain = TypeVar('Domain')
Range = TypeVar('Range')
Map = Callable[[Domain], Range]

Constructor = Callable[..., Domain]
Initializer = Callable[..., None]


def generate_repr(constructor_or_initializer: Union[Constructor, Initializer],
                  *,
                  field_seeker: Callable[[Domain, str], Any] = getattr
                  ) -> Map[Domain, str]:
    signature = inspect.signature(constructor_or_initializer)
    parameters = OrderedDict(signature.parameters)
    # remove `self`
    parameters.popitem(0)
    to_positional_argument_string = repr
    to_keyword_argument_string = '{}={!r}'.format

    def __repr__(self: Domain) -> str:
        return (type(self).__qualname__
                + '(' + ', '.join(to_arguments_strings(self)) + ')')

    def to_arguments_strings(object_: Domain) -> Iterable[str]:
        for parameter_name, parameter in parameters.items():
            field = field_seeker(object_, parameter_name)
            if parameter.kind == inspect._VAR_POSITIONAL:
                if isinstance(field, abc.Iterator):
                    yield '...'
                else:
                    yield from map(to_positional_argument_string, field)
            elif parameter.kind == inspect._VAR_KEYWORD:
                yield from map(to_keyword_argument_string,
                               field.keys(), field.values())
            elif parameter.kind in {inspect._POSITIONAL_ONLY,
                                    inspect._POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD}:
                yield to_positional_argument_string(field)
            else:
                yield to_keyword_argument_string(parameter_name, field)

    return __repr__
```

## Test

Let's define our class like

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, positional, *variadic_positional, keyword_only,
                 **variadic_keyword):
        self.positional = positional
        self.variadic_positional = variadic_positional
        self.keyword_only = keyword_only
        self.variadic_keyword = variadic_keyword

    __repr__ = generate_repr(__init__)
```

After that

```
>>> A(1, 2, 3, keyword_only='some', a={'sample': 42}, b={1, 2})
A(1, 2, 3, keyword_only='some', b={1, 2}, a={'sample': 42})
```

Comment: [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) does this for you. It has even been [backported to 3.6](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it looks like most of your code can't be simplified. However I found:

2. `to_positional_argument_string` is a mouth full, and people would understand your code easier if you just use `repr`.
3. `to_keyword_argument_string` is another mouth full and so you could call it `kw_repr`.
4. You may want to add a comment explaining what `isinstance(field, abc.Iterator)` is for. This is because at first it confused me.
5. [Controversial] You can change your code so that you don't need to be passed `constructor_or_initializer`. To do this you'd create `parameters` when `__repr__` is first used.

Comment: about `self`: this is incorrect, because for `__new__` (which can be used for immutable types) first parameter is `cls`, not `self`

Comment: about "major unusable bug": this can be simply handled by passing custom `field_seeker`, no need in extra mapping parameter

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It can actually be anything you want it to be, but yes you're correct in that case.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Ah yes it can. That would make `field_seeker` quite unsightly imo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you but I prefer decorators. I have two solutions:

1. for any immutable.
2. (similar to yours except there is is no `yield from` or other wizardry :o) for any objects that respect your convention:

```
def __init__(self, <args>): self.<args> = <args>
```

The thing is (in my mind at least), that if you make a module, we don't care how complicated it is on the inside, but what matters is how easy it is to use it. Which is why I prefer decorators, they are non-intrusive by nature.

**custom_module1.py:** *(for any immutable)*

```
def repr_maker(cls):
    class Representer(cls):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self._args = args
            self._kwargs = kwargs

        def __repr__(self):
            return cls.__name__ + '(' + ', '.join(
                [repr(i) for i in self._args]
                + [i + '=' + repr(j) for i, j in self._kwargs.items()]
            ) + ')'
    return Representer
```

**custom_module2.py:** *(for any object that respect your convention)*

```
def repr_maker(cls):
    def represent(self):
        params = list(inspect.signature(cls.__init__).parameters.items())
        return cls.__name__ + '(' + ', '.join(
            [repr(getattr(self, name))
             for name, param in params
             if (param.kind.name == 'POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD'
                 and name != 'self')]
            + [', '.join(repr(value) for value in getattr(self, name))
               for name, param in params
               if param.kind.name == 'VAR_POSITIONAL']
            + [name + '=' + repr(getattr(self, name))
               for name, param in params
               if param.kind.name == 'KEYWORD_ONLY']
            + [', '.join(kw + '=' + repr(value)
                         for kw, value in getattr(self, name).items())
               for name, param in params
               if param.kind.name == 'VAR_KEYWORD']
        ) + ')'
    cls.__repr__ = represent
    return cls
```

**my_program.py**

```
from custom_module import repr_maker

@repr_maker
class A:
    def __init__(self, positional, *variadic_positional, keyword_only,
                 **variadic_keyword):
        self.positional = positional
        self.variadic_positional = variadic_positional
        self.keyword_only = keyword_only
        self.variadic_keyword = variadic_keyword


print(repr(A(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, keyword_only=10, babar="le plus beau des éléphants")))
# A(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, keyword_only=10, babar='le plus beau des éléphants')
```

It is clean, reusable and does not pollute the actual code with extra stuff.

Comment: [As pointed out in the comments to my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/213875#comment413703_213892) this is intended to work with `__new__` too. Yours, currently, only works with `__init__`.

Comment: I am not familiar with `__new__` but it seems to me that it would be the same thing.

Comment: I edited my function, this looks like the simplest solution, you could also pass an argument to the decorator but then you have to nest functions even more.

Comment: Just to note `__new__` can be created without the `args` and `kwargs` parameters. And still be the intended target. Infact, as pointed out in `A` those are just standard names, which can be replaced with anything. I'd also like to point out, that this deviates quite a bit from the question in that there is no `field_seeker`. If you look at my edits you'll see it's a rather _useful_ aspect.

Comment: Yes, 'args' and 'kwargs' are the default, meaning that the only way it has changed is if you overload `__new__`. I will agree this is ugly, I will revert it and let's let leave this answer there. I stay convinced that decorators are the way to go here even if my particular implementation didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I'm trying to write classes as simple as possible, most of them ends in something like [...] initializer parameters names corresponds to fields names, so we can get initializer arguments by simply getattr'ing corresponding fields.

This feels exactly like what [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) were added for. The advantage for your use case is that support for `__repr__` is built-in.

Comment: there is no `dataclasses` module in Python3.5 (and can't be due to [variable annotations syntax support](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep526)), which is my main option now

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Since you mentionned Python 3.5+, I thought I’d give it a try. Didn't know it was 3.5 exactly.